# Create function to group sequence at breakpoints

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a function that takes two sequences and groups the elements first based on the "breakpoints" included in the second. An example:

```
val ls = ('a' to 'z').map(_.toString)
// IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, ...)

val breakpoints = Seq("c", "f", "j")

grouper(ls, breakpoints)
// Seq(Seq("a", "b"), Seq("c", "d", "e"), Seq("f", "g", "h", "i"), Seq("j", ...))
```

I've tried to do this with recursive calls to `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` (as I might in a language like Haskell), but as my current function doesn't use tail recursion, I receive a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Here's the function:

```
def grouper(strings: Seq[String], breaks: Seq[String]): Seq[Seq[String]] = strings match {
  case Nil => Seq()
  case s => s.takeWhile(breaks.contains(_)) +: grouper(s.dropWhile(breaks.contains(_)), breaks)
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` can be replaced by `span`.

```
def grouper(xs: Seq[String], breaks: Seq[String]): Seq[Seq[String]] = breaks match{
 case Nil => Seq(xs)
 case h::t => {
   val split = xs.span(x => x != h); 
   split._1 +: grouper(split._2, t);
 }
}

scala> grouper(ls, breakpoints)
res5: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(Vector(a, b), Vector(c, d, e), Vector(f, g, h, i),
  Vector(j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z))
```

From the API on `span`: *Note: c span p is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p), provided the evaluation of the predicate p does not cause any side-effects.*

Comment: You can not safely pattern match a **Seq** with `Nil` and `::`. That would only work if by chance, at runtime that **Seq** is actually a **List**. Also `+:` could have a really bad performance, since you do not control the underlying collection type. **Seq**, is simply a failed abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement -- `span` is definitely nicer here! (and, more importantly, doesn't result in stack overflow:))

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, I always prefer to write my own *tail-recursive* function, operating o **Lists**.

```
import Ordering.Implicits._

def group[A : Ordering](data: List[A], breakPoints: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  def takeUntil(list: List[A], breakPoint: A): (List[A], List[A]) = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: List[A]): (List[A], List[A]) =
      remaining match {
        case x :: xs if (x < breakPoint) =>
          loop(remaining = xs, x :: acc)

        case _ =>
          (acc.reverse, remaining)
      }

    loop(remaining = list, acc = List.empty)
  }

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remainingElements: List[A], remainingBreakPoints: List[A], acc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] =
    remainingBreakPoints match {
      case breakPoint :: remainingBreakPoints =>
        val (group, remaining) = takeUntil(remainingElements, breakPoint)
          loop(
            remainingElements = remaining,
            remainingBreakPoints,
            group :: acc
          )

      case Nil =>
        (remainingElements :: acc).reverse
    }

  loop(
    remainingElements = data.sorted,
    remainingBreakPoints = breakPoints.sorted,
    acc = List.empty
  )
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
group(data = ('a' to 'z').toList, breakPoints = List('c', 'f', 'j')) 
//res: List[List[Char]] = List(
//  List('a', 'b'),
//  List('c', 'd', 'e'),
//  List('f', 'g', 'h', 'i'),
//  List('j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
// )
```

This function will generate always a list of `length = length(breakPoints) + 1`.
If there are no more elements, it will generate empty lists.
*(you can edit the code for your concrete requirements)*

Comment: Very nice! Need to spend a bit of time wrapping my head around it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a bit different approach:

```
 def grouper(strings: Seq[String], breaks: Seq[String]): Seq[Seq[String]] =  {
    var i = 0
    (for(x <- strings) yield {if (breaks.contains(x)) {i=i+1}; (x,i)})
      .groupBy(_._2).map(_._2.map(_._1)).toList
  }

 grouper(ls,breakpoints).foreach(println(_))


Vector(f, g, h, i)
Vector(c, d, e)
Vector(j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)
Vector(a, b)
```